# flutter navigation to new screen not working

Tags: dart, flutter

I am building a login screen that passes data to a home screen and when I click on the login button nothing happens. No error but also no sending to a new screen.

here is the button code:

```
    Widget submitButton()
    {
 return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child:RaisedButton(
        child: Text('LOGIN'),
        onPressed: (){
          if(formKey.currentState.validate()){

            formKey.currentState.save();
             print('Time to save $emailAddress and $passWord to my API');
             Navigator.push(
               context,
                      new MaterialPageRoute(
                     builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                     new Home()));

                  }
               },

        )
 );
```

here is my routes.dart file

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import '../screens/home.dart';
 import 'package:lbconnectv3/main.dart';

 final routes = {
  '/home':         (BuildContext context) => new Home(),
   '/' :          (BuildContext context) => new LBConnectApp(),
   };
```

### EDIT

FULL CODE for main.dart, it basically has a form with 2 text fields for a login. No errors in console and it enters the if statement.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'utils/validation.dart';
import 'screens/home.dart';
import 'utils/routes.dart';

 void main() => runApp(new LBConnectApp());

  class LBConnectApp extends StatefulWidget {

  createState()
  {
     return new LBConnectAppState();
   }

   } 

   class LBConnectAppState extends State<LBConnectApp> with Validation
   {

      final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
      String emailAddress = '';
      String passWord = '';
      Widget build(context) {
      return MaterialApp(

       title: "LB Connect",
        home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF0099a9),
        body:
        Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
        child: Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: Column(
         children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
            child:Image.asset('images/lb_connect_trans.png')
           ),
           emailField(),
           passwordField(),   
          submitButton(),
        ],
         ),      
        ),
       )
       ),  
       );  
       }

       Widget emailField()
       {
         return TextFormField(
         keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          decoration : InputDecoration(
           labelText: 'Email Address',
         ),

         validator: validateEmail,
         onSaved: (String value){

           emailAddress = value;

         },

       );
       }

       Widget passwordField()
       {
           return TextFormField(
         obscureText: true,
         decoration : InputDecoration(
           labelText: 'Password',

         ),

         validator: validatePassword,
          onSaved: (String value){

            passWord = value;
         },

         );
       }

       Widget submitButton()
      {
          return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child:RaisedButton(
        child: Text('LOGIN'),
        onPressed: (){
          if(formKey.currentState.validate()){

            formKey.currentState.save();
             print('Time to save $emailAddress and $passWord to my API');
             Navigator.push(
               context,
                      new MaterialPageRoute(
                     builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                     new Home()));

                  }
               },

            )
       );
     }

    }
```

Comment: Everything looks good to me. Is it entering into the `if` in your `onPressed`. Are you getting any error in console

Comment: post full code, to see how do you use the widget

Comment: and try to use pushNamed('/home');

Comment: I'll edit and post full code. No errors in the console and it enters the if statement.

Comment: full code posted for main.dart

Comment: I tried pushnamed and same result. no navigation.

Comment: when i changed to pushnamed i did get this error in debug:  "══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4133): The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter ( 4133): Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
I/flutter ( 4133): The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a
I/flutter ( 4133): descendant of a Navigator widget."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After messing around with my app I figured out the issue :)

I had to wrap my class with a Material App and then add my routes property to it. Here is the correct code:

```
 void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
 routes: routes,
 home: LBConnectApp()
 )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
void main() => runApp(new LBConnectApp());
```

with this and it will work as per your expectation

```
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: new ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: new LBConnectApp(),
);
}
}
```

Comment: that did not work. same error. Thats just the class name

Comment: This is the error im trying to fix. it has to do with the context im using, im completely new to flutter so any suggestions would be great.   ""

Comment: The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.