# Navigate to a new screen in Flutter

Tags: dart, navigation, flutter

How do you navigate to a new screen in Flutter?

These questions are similar, but are asking more than I am.

- [Flutter - Navigate to a new screen, and clear all the previous screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689049/flutter-navigate-to-a-new-screen-and-clear-all-the-previous-screens)
- [Flutter: How do I navigate to a new screen using DropDownMenuItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51137381/flutter-how-do-i-navigate-to-a-new-screen-using-dropdownmenuitems)
- [Flutter: Move to a new screen without back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037710/flutter-move-to-a-new-screen-without-back)
- [flutter navigation to new screen not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51976964/flutter-navigation-to-new-screen-not-working)

I am adding an answer below.

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about that. I think there's a limit to how _low level_ a question is. I mean if this question/answer is fine, then we could do one for literally any widgets from the framework

Comment: Sure, but your question falls into "too broad" IMO.

Comment: I think there has to be a limit how low level a question is. As @RémiRousselet says we can do it for any widget from the framework, plus documentation for this question is pretty obvious.

Comment: The flutter doc is pretty straightforward on this subject. https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

Answer (score 74, accepted):

### Navigate to a new screen:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen()));
```

where `context` is the BuildContext of a widget and `NewScreen` is the name of the second widget layout.

[image]

### Code

*main.dart*

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home Screen')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text(
            'Navigate to a new screen >>',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            _navigateToNextScreen(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _navigateToNextScreen(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen()));
  }
}

class NewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('New Screen')),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'This is a new screen',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### See also

- [Documentation](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)
- [Navigator and Routes and Transitions... Oh, My! - Simon Lightfoot | Flutter Europe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CYTTW6PMoc)

Comment: and what is the reason for that? you are doing that every second day... why? maybe you should write a blog or something?

Comment: @westdabestdb he does it 3-4 times a week, i have no idea what is a purpose of doing that...

Comment: @westdabestdb `"and we all know Flutter has well-written documentation."` - well, i would argue with that... ;-(

Comment: @pskink I honestly like their documentation. It used to be worse than current, but their last polish & improvement to flutter.io made things a lot better.

Comment: @westdabestdb sure your right, but still, i am finding myself quite often after reading some new docs for 10 minutes or so i go to the class source files and they tell me whats going on better and faster than the corresponding docs...

Comment: @pskink True, reading the source code is 10x better than spending time with docs, so doing both is the way to the solution.

Comment: I answer questions on SO because it helps me learn better. Almost every question I answer is a question I have myself. When I have a question I Google it. If I can't find a quick answer or a duplicate on SO then I write a Q&A pair.

Comment: `RaisedButton` is now deprecated and replaced by `ElevatedButton`. Please, someone update the example accordingly. I'm new to flutter and might mess up.

Answer (score 23):

To load new screens with Flutter pre-canned [animations](https://github.com/flutter/packages/tree/master/packages/animations), use their respective transition classes. For example:

**Container Transformation**

[image]

Basically we have the first widget or screen transform into the next screen. For this we need to use `OpenContainer`. The following code illustrates an item in a ListView transformed to its details page.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      elevation: 2.0,
      child: OpenContainer(
        transitionType: ContainerTransitionType.fadeThrough,
        closedColor: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
        closedElevation: 0.0,
        openElevation: 4.0,
        transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
        openBuilder: (BuildContext context, VoidCallback _) => THENEXTSCREEN(),
        closedBuilder: (BuildContext _, VoidCallback openContainer) {
          return ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.album),
            title: Text("ITEM NAME"),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Shared Axis**

[image]

This transition is similar to that in Tab or Stepper. We need `SharedAxisTransition`, `PageTransitionSwitcher`, along with a state to model transition between active and previous page. If we only switch between two pages we can use a simple boolean `isFirstPage` for it. Here's the snippet with Provider as state management:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<YourState>(
      builder: (context, state, child) {
        return PageTransitionSwitcher(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
          reverse: !state.isFirstPage, // STATE
          transitionBuilder: (
            Widget child,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          ) {
            return SharedAxisTransition(
              child: child,
              animation: animation,
              secondaryAnimation: secondaryAnimation,
              transitionType: SharedAxisTransitionType.horizontal,
            );
          },
          child: state.isFirstPage? FIRSTPAGE() : SECONDPAGE(), // STATE
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Note that in all these scenarios we don't use Navigator and MaterialPageRoute. All these codes are derived from [animations repo](https://github.com/flutter/packages/tree/master/packages/animations/lib/src) so you may want to check it out first.

Answer (score 14):

Navigate to next screen with back using `Navigator.push()`

```
Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),);
```

Navigate to next screen without back using `Navigator.pushReplacement()`

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
onTap: () {
  Navigator.push(context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextScreenName()));
}
```

Comment: While your answer may be correct (I don't know if it is), it would be a lot more valuable to future searchers if you explain what it does and why it works

Comment: Hi @MindSwipe please refer the question. 
So basically, It is used to navigate from one screen to another screen

Answer (score 5):

Here is a full example of routes push / pop:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Routes',
      routes: {
        '/login': (BuildContext context) => Login(),
        // add another route here
        // '/register': (BuildContext context) => Register(),
      },
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Routes'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // This gives the back button:
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/login');

                // This doesn't give the back button (it replaces)
                //Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/login');
              },
              child: Text('Login'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Login Page'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // This will only work for pushNamed
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: Text('Go back'),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are familiar with web development this approach is similar to routing.

*main.dart*

```
void main() {
  setupLocator();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      routes: {
        '/' : (BuildContext context)=>HomePage(),
        '/register' : (BuildContext context)=>RegisterPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

You can add button `onPressed` event from the `homepage.dart` to navigate `register.dart`  as follows.

```
onPressed: (){
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/register');
 },
```

Answer (score 4):

**`In formal method :`**

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Second()));
```

**In GetX method :**

```
Get.to(Second());
```

If we can navigate screen into another page and delete current page from stack then we can use method which is define below :

```
Get.off(Third());
```

If we can navigate screen into another page and delete all route or page from stack then we can use the method which is define below :

```
Get.offAll(Third());
```

If we want to use Navigator.pop() then GetX give a Method which is define below :

```
Get.back();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: (){
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const AddUser()));
  },
  child: const Icon(Icons.add),
),
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. This is particularly important when answering old questions (this one is nearly 4 years old) with existing answers. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked, and how it improves upon what is already here. See [answer].

Answer (score 2):

you can use that way in your build widget

`onTap: () { Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => NewScreen()));},`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following code

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourNextScreen())),
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a good tutorial that I have followed along, it is very comprehensive with screenshots and step by step, you can also download the code and just run it. Very helpful for me learning Flutter especially I am totally a begineer.

https://medium.com/@misterflutter/lesson-5-creating-new-screens-f740994190c7

https://medium.com/@misterflutter/lesson-6-creating-new-screens-part-2-4997085a43af?sk=d2a0fb723af42b78800f7cf19b312b62

Answer (score 1):

```
flutter_quick_router: ^0.0.2
```

The QuickRouter provides handy methods for navigating between routes using the Navigator widget in Flutter. It supports both regular and restorable routes and offers various transition types.

To navigate to other screen

```
context.to(const SecondScreen());
```

Going back old screen

```
context.back();
```

Answer (score 0):

With the [Get plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/get#route-management), you can navigate to a new page by simply calling

```
Get.to(Page());
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can present the next screen

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
   MaterialPageRoute(fullscreenDialog: true,
   builder: (context) => const NewScreen(),
   ),
);
```