# Make links clickable in Flutter if rendered via Wordpress JSON API

Tags: json, wordpress, flutter, api, rest

Is there a way we can make the links in Flutter clickable if they are being fetched via JSON API? I mean, I can see that my links get a different color, but when I try to click on it, nothing happens. Trying it on an emulator, have not released the app yet.

JSON:

```
"content": {
  "rendered": "<p>Absolutely great movie <a href="test">Test</a>!</p>\n"},
```

I need to make sure that "Test" is clickable and sends me to the post in my app.

This is the content JSON file:

```
class Content {
  String? raw;
  String? rendered;
  bool? protected;
  int? blockVersion;

  Content({this.rendered});

  Content.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    raw = json['raw'];
    rendered = json['rendered'];
    protected = json['protected'];
    blockVersion = json['block_version'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    
    data['raw'] = this.raw;
    data['rendered'] = this.rendered;
    data['protected'] = this.protected;
    data['block_version'] = this.blockVersion;
    
    return data;
  }
}
```

How can I make them clickable automatically?

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _content = widget.post.content?.rendered ?? "";
    _content = _content.replaceAll('localhost', '192.168.6.165');
  }
```

The text itself:

```
Html(
            data: _content // this is where all texts are,
            // blockSpacing: 0.0,
          ),
```

If I use RichText, it gives me the following error:

> error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter
> type 'InlineSpan'. (argument_type_not_assignable)

Comment: Are you trying to  open link on browser

Comment: I am using an emulator, currently.

Comment: you can use rich text for clickable text

Comment: well are you trying to open the link by tapping on link text?

Comment: Yes, correct @YeasinSheikh.

Comment: Have added a bit more info in the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        text: 'Hello ',
        style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
        children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(
              text: 'world!',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          TextSpan(
              text: ' click here!',
              recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                ..onTap = () => print('click')),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: How does this solve it? This is my content: _content = widget.post.content?.rendered ?? "";

It is not a specific text, but it's a text coming from JSON. Please see post and last edit below.

Comment: Could you check the edited post?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I partially solved it.

Still, the problem I have with this is that it opens a browser - I need it to go to the posts itself on my app, but I can't get this to work. Just sharing anyway.

```
    Html(
    data: _content,
    onLinkTap: (url, _, __, ___) async {
      if (await launch(url!)) {
        await launch(
          url,
        );
      }
    },
  ),
```

Comment: you need to navigate to other page. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165549/navigate-to-a-new-screen-in-flutter

Comment: But how can we transform them to a detail page if first fetched from the API?