# Flutter: Where to add a button to get to the menu?

Tags: flutter, dart

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIHhS.jpg how do i move the start button down using alignment axies? i have created another page for the start button to go into that new page (settingpage.dart).
how to i navigate to the next page ?

Thanks for your help.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp/updown.dart';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({super.key});

  @override
  State<Homepage> createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  double UpdownY = -0.6;

  void jump() {
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 50), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        UpdownY -= 0.05;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Center(
                child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Updown(
                  updownY: UpdownY,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                    onLongPress: () => "Navigate",
                    child: const Image(
                        height: 100,
                        width: 100,
                        image: AssetImage("lib/images/start-png.png")))
              ],
            )),
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can add it as a children to Stack. Like Updown(...), ElevatedButton(...)

Comment: thanks for the reply, possible to edit my current code as an example ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this assuming you use `ElevatedButton`

```
      @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              body: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    child: Center(
                        child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Updown(
                          updownY: UpdownY,
                        ),
                    GestureDetector(
                onLongPress: () => "Navigate",
                child: const Image(
                        height: 100,
                        width: 500,
                        image: AssetImage("lib/images/start-png.png"))),
                ),
              )
                      ],
                    )),
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        }
```

Comment: ya possible to make a png button ?

Comment: In that case you can Image.network("your url") and wrap it with gesture detector to detect clicks

Comment: Hi, i have the png file in my image , my plan is to add a png button to go a next page. no matter what i add i keep get wavy red line. i am kinda lost on this part.

Comment: I've updated the answer, you can just wrap your image like this

Comment: thanks buddy, i have added and place a alignment on top height but my icon still stuck on the top left.

Comment: Youre welcome, can you update the code with your last attempts?

Comment: done, not the icon is at center top, how i adjust the alignment it still dun work

Comment: Sorry i havent quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: hi i have added the link on my first post, thanks for assisting , i still very new to this :(

Comment: I've updated again. Can you check it out

Comment: i getting bottom overflowed by 297 pixel , i will paste my code and attach the SS

Comment: Ss doesnt seem to work

Comment: so sorry its done.

Comment: hi , i mange to solve the overflow issue , now i want to be able to adjust the icon further down and navigate to another page , i cant get the code right.

Comment: oh great. To align your icons you can use mainAxisAlignment property of Column. There are various kinds of values, try all of them to see how they work. or just put SİzedBox(height:15), between your two icons. For navigation follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165549/navigate-to-a-new-screen-in-flutter

Comment: Hi, thanks , i had align the image properly. 

i am have question on navigation, do creator normally create a new .dart file for the next screen or stick the coding to the same page ?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant you want to show the AppBar menu, so you can try this:

```
Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('My app'),
              centerTitle: true,
)
```

Or if you meant to add a normal button to the screen, so you can add many kinds of buttons (elevated - material - text - ...etc).

In general I use `MaterialButton`, it's simply to use it, like this:

```
MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              child: const Text('Test button'),
            ),
```

Comment: thanks but i did add a png button but now trying to navigate into another setting page.

Comment: it's easy to add navigation to the button..
Just add this line:
`Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page(),),)`

Comment: thanks will try it u can look above i have updated my code , just the alignment is off. any idea why